# Does it make sense to use a Future<T> with a CountDownLatch?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am submitting two jobs using an ExecutorService as below.

```
final Future<String> futureResultA = executor.submit(jobA);
final Future<String> futureResultB = executor.submit(jobB);
```

Now, when I want to get the result from this future, I was calling the get() method to await and get the results.

```
futureResultA.get()
```

Now, will using a CountDownLatch give me any advantage if I initialize a latch and call countdown on the latch within each of my jobs?

Comment: I don't see the point, unless you need each thread to follow up with some action once the latch is released.

Comment: These seem like orthogonal issues. You use the Future to obtain a result from a submitted Callable, and you use a CountDownLatch when you want to be notified when all threads have completed -- the two are not directly related, and you use one, the other or both together when and where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the results of the jobs are unrelated to each other, the answer is NO (CountDownLatch will not add any value)

Using a CompletionService will give you an advantage though. Currently, if you wait on Job-A first, then that call blocks until Job-A is done. Only then you can move on to checking the results of Job-B. So even if Job-B finishes before job-A, you can't use its result util Job-A has also finished.

Using CompletionService, you can get the results from whichever job finishes first and use them without waiting for the other -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Callable<String> jobA = () -> {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            return "JobA's result";
        };

        Callable<String> jobB = () -> {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return "JobB's result";
        };

        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        CompletionService<String> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
        completionService.submit(jobA);
        completionService.submit(jobB);


        Future<String> futureWhichCompletedFirst = completionService.take();
        System.out.println(futureWhichCompletedFirst.get());

        Future<String> futureWhichCompletedNext = completionService.take();
        System.out.println(futureWhichCompletedNext.get());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CountDownLatch has a counter field, which you can decrement as we require. We can then use it to block a calling thread until it’s been counted down to zero.
As in your case Future.get() already serving this purpose,  you don't need CountDownLatch. I would rather say it will be overkill.